# How to properly copy into an already initialized object variable

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, dynamic-arrays, copy-elision

```
#include <iostream>

class MyArray {
    public:
        MyArray(int* array, int size) {
            this->size = size;
            this->array = new int[size];
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                this->array[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
        MyArray(const MyArray& myArray) {
            std::cout << "copying: ";
            myArray.print();
            std::cout << std::endl;
            size = myArray.size;
            this->array = new int[size];
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = myArray.array[i];
            }
        }
        ~MyArray() {
            std::cout << "destroying: ";
            print();
            std::cout << std::endl;
            delete []array;
        }
        const void print() const{
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                std::cout << array[i];
            }
        }
        int* array;
        int size;
};

int main() {
    int array1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int array2[4] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
    MyArray myArray1(array1, 4);
    MyArray myArray2(array2, 4);
    MyArray myArray3 = myArray1;
    myArray1 = myArray2;
}
```

In the sample above, I can copy an object into a new variable, myArray3, and the copy constructor prints "copying: 1234" as it should.  When I copy myArray2 into the previously initialized myArray1, the copy constructor does not print (possibly due to some kind of [Copy Elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)). When the destructor is called after the variable goes out of scope, I get a malloc error for deleting the same variable twice.  Is there a clean way to copy over an already initialized object variable (myArray1 = myArray2) without running into this issue with the destructor?

Comment: I think you might want to override the assign operator.

Comment: Please learn about [the rules of three, five and zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If you want to implement your own explicit memory handling (like you currently do) then you should follow the rule of three or five. But I rather recommend you use `std::vector` and use the rule of zero instead.

Comment: @JackT.Spades -- you **override** a virtual function, by providing a definition in the derived class with the same signature. What's needed here is to **overload** the assignment operator.

Comment: @JackT.Spades Thanks for the help.  I was conflating the copy constructor and assignment operator as the same thing.